# Access Spring Security annotations from Spring Security filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

So I am currently migrating struts 1 action classes to spring mvc, and also adding spring security. In older implementation, what is happening is when the user is authenticated we put a `HashMap<String, AuthObj>` in session object where key for this `HashMap` is the role/privilege and value `AuthObj` is a object which contains multiple props related to that particular 'Role' and that particular user which was authenticated.

Then there is a `org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor` which is executed just before any struts action is invoked, what we are doing in this `TilesRequestProcessor` is we access the action class config `org.apache.struts.config.ActionConfig` to read the role/privilege required to invoke that particular action class and then put some properties in request/session object based on the 'role' required to invoke that action class, and the key of this property is same for every action class so that when we access this property in action class later, we don't have to use different key.

My question was how can this be achieved using spring mvc and spring security, important thing is when we put this obj in session/request object, the key should be same for every action class, otherwise i'll have to modify 100s of methods in older code which i am migrating from struts to spring.

In my new implementation I am using annotation `@Secured("ROLE")` on spring mvc controllers, what I want to do is access the value of annotation `@Secured("ROLE")` on the controller being invoked based on the request url using filter, then set a parameter on request object `request.setParameter(key, value)` based on the supplied value of annotation which is 'ROLE' in this case.

I wanted to know how do I access this value of annotation and which spring security filter I should be extending to add a parameter to request object `request.setParameter(key, value)` and this request parameter should be accessible in controller as well

Comment: Look as using AOP to intercept the requests. If every method with your annotation takes has an HttpServleRequest as a param you can set the value in the advice. Otherwise looking at using `ThreadLocal` storage in the aspect. See for starters: https://blog.jayway.com/2015/09/08/defining-pointcuts-by-annotations/

Comment: @AlanHay AOP is one way to do it, but if I add AOP it will add one more layer to the application which will further increase the complexity of the application which i dont want. What i was wondering is if there is some SpringContext object which carry the information related to `@Secured` annotations used on controllers which i could access from the filter..